# postgres datetime field "x00008F4900000000"

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, datetime

I have generate a table data in MS SQL Server to insert it into Postgresql.

The script has this format of insert

```
INSERT INTO Bank_Draft_Information (Bank_Code, Draft_Type, Transaction_Type, Institution_Code, Serial_Number, Bank_Draft_Date, Total_Amount, Balance_Amount, Created_By, Created_On, Amended_By, Amended_On) 
VALUES

 (6, 'C', 'I', NULL, NULL, 0x00008F4900000000 AS DateTime, 1500.0000, 1000.0000, 1, 0x0000950400000000 AS DateTime, 19, 0x0000A32400000000 AS DateTime));
```

Got error this error,

> syntax error at or near "x00008F4900000000"

More, have no access to the MS SQL Server db anymore. How can I convert this into postgres date time object?

Comment: Figure out what date it is really representing and then use the appropriate literal.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know that format is this date in. did you know?

Comment: A SQL Server `timestamp` has nothing to do with a "real" timestamp. It's more like a row version. It contains binary data that can't be converted to anything usable outside of SQL Server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why do you think it's a timestamp and not a datetime?

Comment: Because the hex representation shown is the default output format of a `timestamp` column.

Comment: @MTaqi . . . Store the date in a SQL Server database, read the value, and use that for the Postgres insert.

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery):

> So how does SQL Server internally store the dates? It uses 8 bytes to store a datetime value—the first 4 for the date and the second 4 for the time. SQL Server can interpret both sets of 4 bytes as integers. For the date portion, the value SQL Server stores is the number of days before or after a base date of January 1, 1900. (...)
>
> SQL Server stores the second integer for the time as the number of clock ticks after midnight. A second contains 300 ticks, so a tick equals 3.3 milliseconds (ms). You can see the values for days and clock ticks by converting a datetime value to a binary(8) value and using the substring function to extract each set of 4 bytes. The code in Figure 3 then converts each set of 4 bytes into an integer.

Considering that I'm guessing that `x00008F49` probably represents the number of days past since January 1, 1900, And the rest of the strings is probably time representation. Since it's all 0 it represents midnight.